# SSIS SMO Connection to SQL Server, using the Transfer Objects Task, throws various connection type errors

Tags: sql-server, ssis, database-connection

We are running an SSIS Package from a SQL Server 2014 instance which connects to a remote SQL 2016 Server through an SMO connection in a Transfer Objects Task. This task retrieves schemas, tables and SP's. The SSIS package has three of these tasks running in parallel which connect to three different Db's on the same SQL server.

Things had been running fine until a day last week the owners of the remote SQL Server decided to create a new user/password combo to give to us. No permissions changed or anything else, only the u/p.

After they did that the package has been failing with various connection type errors. The errors happen randomly on the three parallel tracks. Here are the errors:

> Failed to retrieve data for this request.

> Invalid Operation: The connection is closed.

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

> Property TextHeader is not available for StoredProcedure '[Sp Name]'. This property may not exist for this object, or may not be retrievable due to insufficient access rights. The text is encrypted.

But on the DB side the error the profiler was showing was the password was invalid. This is not true.

After some extensive troubleshooting we tried giving he user SA rights, which did not help. On further work we tried changing the password to 123 (while keeping SA rights,) the prior password had been a 10+ char non-alpha-numeric (had the ! char) password, for example aBc12dEF3!!!. We tried removing the ! chars and various other iterations, but that didn't work then we finally got it down to the password being 123.

This final password change worked. But obviously this is not normal, we cannot have user with SA rights and 123 as password.

Does anyone have any ideas, advice, direction on what could be going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you run the SSIS package, as a SQL Server Agent job executiog SSIS-package? Is the package run from SSISDB or from file system? How is the connection configured?

Comment: Normally runs as a SQL Job, but we also have been running it manually from local for testing. Both ways issue the same errors. Connection is SMO with remote server, U/P. Everything else is default settings for SMO connections.